# Deal with NAN values when creating models with python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nan, logistic-regression, data-cleaning

I have to explain a variable(Y) by a variable matrix (X)..  I have NAN values in my Y which is THE VARIABLE TO EXPLAIN. My NAN values takes half of my observations.
Should I delete lines of my Y that are NAN??

X: (int matrix) cleaned and doens't contain NAN values. 
Y: takes (YES, NO, NAN). 
How can i do

Thank YoU!!

Comment: Please edit your question, it is not readable for anybody.

Comment: This isn't a technical question. You have to ask yourself why you do have missing values in your Y variable: issue with data collection? Does NaN actually represent something? Hard to say without knowing the problem. Edit: I suspect this is a machine learning problem. In ML data cleaning, preparation, and exploration is 80% of the task.

Comment: NAN doesn't say nothing.. NAN  =  we don't know the response

Comment: Then what's your question?

Comment: Hi Mathilde, you can probably better ask your question on Data Science Stack Exchange. StackOverflow is more about programming.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To answer this question I think you need to answer the more fundamental question "is Y=NaN a label?"

If you want the trained model to predict one of three labels (Yes, No, NaN) then fill the NaNs with a label (e.g. "Missing"). If you don't (Yes or No) then I don't see how you can train on observations with no target. Drop those and train on the rest.

Comment: NAN = a missing value .. That will not help me to build a model. I must concentrate on Y= Yes AND Y= No. EDIT:  I want to predict one of two values (Yes, No)

Comment: I addressed that, I told you if that was the case to drop those lines...

Comment: If the question is resolved you can mark it as answered @Mathilde